# Issue with Inner Join Queries and Receiving Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having an issue with a query I am working on. Basically, I want to display the employee name, their job description, the test type they've taken, their test results, and the date they've taken the test. I am getting duplicate values for the employees in my query. Much help needed
[image]

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` and consider using `JOIN` syntax instead of obsolete `,...,...,.. WHERE ...`

Comment: Thank You. The DISTINCT works.

Comment: Distinct is evil, if primary and foreign keys are correct you soulnd't have doubles.

Comment: @dacrovinunghi The PKs and FKs are correct however. Why is distinct evil?

Comment: suppose 2 tests for one employe the same day

Comment: PKS are unique, so you soulnd have doubles

Comment: @dacrovinunghi Okay. I see. I have all my employees take the test once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the query like this:

```
SELECT emp.Emp_Name,
       emp.Emp_JobDesk,
       tt.Test_Type,
       Test.Test_Results,
       Test.Test_Date

FROM Employee AS emp

--JOIN CoachBooking AS cb ON cb.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
JOIN Test ON Test.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
JOIN TestType as tt ON tt.TestType_ID = Test.TestType_ID

WHERE Test.Test_Results = 'Negative';
```

if multiple for each record use DISTINCT (as suggested in the comments by dacrovinunghi), but I would check the foreign keys.
We don't know your table structure so check the fields name for the synonims

EDIT:
following your structure, you won't need to join CoachBooking, and I added the correct aliases

Comment: if you use aliases, use them throughout :P

Comment: yes, but it's difficult not knowing the table structure :)

Comment: @Gianmarco Okay. That makes sense now. So CoachBooking is redundant?

Comment: you don't need it, you are not using any of its field, so you don't need to include that table.

Comment: @Gianmarco great. Thanks